# body overflow-y:hidden while preserving scroll position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a modal, and I am hiding the scroll bar on the body so the user can only scroll the modal content.

Issue is that when I set `overflow-y:hidden` the body scrolls to top, but I want the page position to be preserved.

```
<body>
    Long content
</body>
```

`scrollY` is at 1000

```
<body style="overflow-y:hidden">
    Long content
</body>
```

`scrollY` goes to 0

I've toyed with the idea of storing the current `scrollY` position and scrolling back there once `overflow-y` is revoked. But its not the effect I desired.

Does anyone else have a better solution?

Comment: Can you please share your complete code so we can help you accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a true modal, and that you are preventing further actions to the main content until it is actioned (closed), why not add your content to a div and place a mask over the div, which would prevent interactions until it it closed. E.g.

```html
<body>
  <div class='content'>
    Long content
  </div>
  <div class="modal-mask">
    <div class="modal">Modal content</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Give the modal mask absolute positioning and covering the screen, then position your modal where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late :-D, but i hope will help somebody

```
let locked = false;
export const addScrollLock = () => {
  if (locked) return;

  document.body.style.top = `${window.pageYOffset}px`;
  document.body.classList.add('scroll-lock'); // class with "overflow: hidden" or "position: fixed"
  locked = true;
};
export const removeScrollLock = () => {
  const scrolled = parseInt(body.style.top) * -1;

  body.classList.remove('scroll-lock');
  window.scrollTo(0, scrolled);
  locked = false;
};
```

Be carefull to call `addScrollLock` before you showing new fullscreen popup, to let the function inside calc right scroll position. Otherwise you will recieve window.pageYOffset = 0 and being scrolled to top after `removeScrollLock` get called.